# select count as a computed column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named "likes" with this structure:
id - auto generated number, 
bywho - user that likes someone ,
identifier - the liked user, 
tip - the category of the like

i'm trying make a list with the most liked users(identifier), my problem is:

i need to generate the ammount of likes as a computed column in the list...

here is what i tried:

```
SELECT u.bywho,u.identifier COUNT(DISTINCT inv_by.identifier) AS lol
FROM  likes u
LEFT  JOIN likes inv_by ON u.identifier = inv_by.identifier
WHERE inv_by.identifier= $this->who AND tip='profil' 
GROUP BY u.identifier ORDER BY lol DESC
```

Comment: Can you define 'computed column'? Apart from a missing comma the query looks okay. I don't understand why you filter by $this->who in your WHERE statement though. If you want a list of all likes you should remove that, because it limits you to the likes the $this->who has made.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this isn't working because of the missing comma and grouping hasn't occured by u.bywho. The problem with doing that is it will give you a breakdown of the count by the person being liked and who liked them. Assuming a person can never be liked more than once, the count would always be one.

Try adding the comma after u.identiier in the select clause as mentioned by another reply.
If that doesn't work try grouping by u.who as well.
If that doesn't work as expected please explain what you expect a liitle more.
I'm guessing you may want to remove something from the select clause. Whatever non-aggregate is left in the select clause needs to be grouped upon.

Comment: a person can have multiple likes, eg multiple rows where the identifier has the same number

Comment: Did you mean to set inv_by.bywho instead of  inv_by.identifer in the where clause?

Comment: If so, change that and remove bywho from the select clause as well.

Comment: Also, You won't need the self join in that case

Comment: If that doesn't help, please add example data and resultset